# Change json field in mysql to include data from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, join

I have these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `config_support_departments` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `support_tickets_filters` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `filter_departments` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

config_support_departments:

```
+----+-------------------------+
| id | title                   |
+----+-------------------------+
|  1 | Projects / File Support |
|  2 | Sales Support           |
|  3 | IT Support              |
+----+-------------------------+
```

support_tickets_filters:

```
+----+--------------------+
| id | filter_departments |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | ["2", "3"]         |
+----+--------------------+
```

What I need is when query the `support_tickets_filters` table to also include the `title` from the `config_support_departments` table. Hence, the result should be something like this:

```
+----+-----------------------------------------------+
| id | filter_departments                            |
+----+-----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | {"2":"Sales Support","3":"IT Support"}         |
+----+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This would be very easy if you didn't use JSON, but used a third table to store the many-to-many associations. JSON makes it seem easy to store data, but it makes it much harder to query that data later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `JSON_OBJECTAGG()` function along with `JSON_TABLE()` if DB version is `8.0+`

```
SELECT s.id, JSON_OBJECTAGG(c.id,c.title) AS filter_departments
  FROM `support_tickets_filters` AS s
  JOIN JSON_TABLE(
                 s.`filter_departments`,
                '$[*]' COLUMNS (id INT PATH '$')
       ) j
  JOIN `config_support_departments` AS c     
    ON j.id = c.id
 GROUP BY s.id
```

For DB version `5.7`, you can use one of the DB metadata tables such as `information_schema.tables` in order to generate index values as `0,1,...` upto the length of the array (`filter_departments`) for extracting the related value from that iteratively

```
SELECT s.id, JSON_OBJECTAGG(c.id,c.title) AS filter_departments
  FROM
  (
   SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS n, s.id,
          JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`filter_departments`,CONCAT('$[',@i,']'))) AS elm
     FROM `support_tickets_filters` AS s
     JOIN (SELECT @i := -1) AS iter
     LEFT JOIN  information_schema.tables AS t
       ON @i < JSON_LENGTH(`filter_departments`) - 1 ) AS s
  JOIN `config_support_departments` AS c     
    ON s.elm = c.id
 GROUP BY s.id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c367e0ec4cd5f1a5abd20f3a69550941)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to achieve this with mysql 5.7?

Comment: you're welcome @MilenMihalev , I've added the case for DB version 5.7.